# Error on integration of splash screen in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've got stuck with an error on integrating splash screen in phonegap.The error shows like :

```
Appidea-iMac:ShopC rantelpereira$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" via git clone
Installing cordova-plugin-splashscreen (android)
Error: Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 3.4.0, failed version requirement: >=3.6.0
    at checkEngines (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:76:29)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

How can I upgrade cordova-android version to 3.6??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to update your Cordova's version.
The latest Cordova version is `4.3.0`, so do you wish to upgrade it to 4.3.0 or wish to stick to the minimum required version?

If you are not sure, you can check the [Changelog](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md) to see if any of the functions you've used got deprecated. But it would be reccomended to update to the latest one if you face no issues.

To update it to v 3.6.0:

```
npm install -g cordova@3.6.0
```

To get the latest version:

```
npm update -g cordova
```

After doing this, you must update your project's platform:

```
cordova platform update android
```

And just to be sure if all went fine, test your project to see if everything runs like before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cordova locally i.e. using the CLI, then you will need to update your phonegap/cordova packages:

`npm update cordova -g`

or

`npm update phonegap -g`

If you are using phonegap build then you will need to update your `config.xml`, as such:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0"/>
```